# Xcode error being thrown in <memory>, "No matching member function for call to `__enable_weak_this`"

Tags: c++, xcode, compilation, compiler-errors, llvm

I'm a compiler noob here, and was mostly wondering if somebody could point me in a direction.  Hopefully the solution is as simple as a build setting

Using Xcode, I am building an Objective-C library that basically wraps a C++ library

My target is a framework

When I try to build, the compiler gives me this error:

> No matching member function for call to `__enable_weak_this`

The error is thrown in `<memory>`, line 4312:
`__r.__enable_weak_this(__r.__ptr_);`

Not sure if it's relevant, but my IDE can recognize that method exists, because I can CMD+click on it, and it brings me to the declaration

I found this thread at llvm.org (https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=27115)
which kind of describes my issue, but it's marked as fixed, and anyways it doesn't seem to be exactly what I'm looking at

In my `.xcproj` build settings, I have (not sure what's relevant):

- Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C: Default compiler (Apple LLVM 7.0)
- C Language Dialect: GNU99 [-std=gnu99]
- C++ Language Dialect: GNU++11 [-std=gnu++11]
- C++ Standard Library: libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support)
- Enable Modules (C and Objective-C): Yes

Is there a setting I could change, point to a different compiler version, or anything that would resolve my issue?  I doubt it's an issue with the C++ library, I'm 99.99% positive I'm doing something wrong. The real problem is I don't have any idea where to start debugging

EDIT:
**Here is the code that looks like is causing the issue:**

```
TSCV::Common::CancellationToken::CancellationToken( bool cancelled )
{
   _isCancelled = make_shared<volatile bool>( cancelled );
   _cancel = [ this ] () { *_isCancelled = true; };
   _cancelled = [ this ] () -> bool { return *_isCancelled; };
}
```

**Here's the error:**

> CancellationToken.cpp:9:19: note: in instantiation of function
>   template specialization 'std::__1::make_shared'
>   requested here    _isCancelled = make_shared( cancelled
>   );

**Expanded the error, here's more details:**
[image]

More error details:

```
CompileC /Users/mattao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ComputerVIsion-bnbfvcebogxuupamklqlxmffldfb/Build/Intermediates/ComputerVision.build/Debug/ComputerVision.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CancellationToken.o /Users/mattao/Code/Common-ComputerVision/Shared/Common/CancellationToken.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/mattao/Code/Common-ComputerVision/Mac
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++ -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/mattao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/mattao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Xclang -fmodule-implementation-of -Xclang ComputerVision -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-c++11-extensions -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -mmacosx-version-min=10.10 -g -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -iquote /Users/mattao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ComputerVIsion-bnbfvcebogxuupamklqlxmffldfb/Build/Intermediates/ComputerVision.build/Debug/ComputerVision.build/ComputerVision-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/mattao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ComputerVIsion-bnbfvcebogxuupamklqlxmffldfb/Build/Intermediates/ComputerVision.build/Debug/ComputerVision.build/ComputerVision-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/mattao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ComputerVIsion-bnbfvcebogxuupamklqlxmffldfb/Build/Intermediates/ComputerVision.build/Debug/ComputerVision.build/ComputerVision-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -ivfsoverlay /Users/mattao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ComputerVIsion-bnbfvcebogxuupamklqlxmffldfb/Build/Intermediates/ComputerVision.build/all-product-headers.yaml -iquote /Users/mattao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ComputerVIsion-bnbfvcebogxuupamklqlxmffldfb/Build/Intermediates/ComputerVision.build/Debug/ComputerVision.build/ComputerVision-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/mattao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ComputerVIsion-bnbfvcebogxuupamklqlxmffldfb/Build/Products/Debug/include -I../OpenCVHeaders -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2 -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/aruco -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/calib3d -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/ccalib -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/core -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/cvv -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/datasets -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/dnn -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/face -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/features2d -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/flann -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/fuzzy -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/hdf -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/highgui -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/imgcodecs -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/imgproc -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/line_descriptor -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/ml -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/objdetect -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/optflow -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/photo -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/reg -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/rgbd -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/saliency -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/sfm -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/shape -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/stereo -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/stitching -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/structured_light -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/superres -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/surface_matching -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/text -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/tracking -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/video -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/videoio -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/videostab -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/xfeatures2d -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/ximgproc -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/xphoto -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/core/hal -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/datasets/tinyxml2 -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/imgproc/detail -I../OpenCVHeaders/opencv2/stitching/detail -I../Shared -I../Shared/Common -I../Shared/Inpainting -I../Shared/Selection -I../Shared/Common/Tests -I../Shared/Inpainting/Tests -I../Shared/Selection/Tests -I/Users/mattao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ComputerVIsion-bnbfvcebogxuupamklqlxmffldfb/Build/Intermediates/ComputerVision.build/Debug/ComputerVision.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/mattao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ComputerVIsion-bnbfvcebogxuupamklqlxmffldfb/Build/Intermediates/ComputerVision.build/Debug/ComputerVision.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/mattao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ComputerVIsion-bnbfvcebogxuupamklqlxmffldfb/Build/Products/Debug -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/mattao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ComputerVIsion-bnbfvcebogxuupamklqlxmffldfb/Build/Intermediates/ComputerVision.build/Debug/ComputerVision.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CancellationToken.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/mattao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ComputerVIsion-bnbfvcebogxuupamklqlxmffldfb/Build/Intermediates/ComputerVision.build/Debug/ComputerVision.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CancellationToken.dia -c /Users/mattao/Code/Common-ComputerVision/Shared/Common/CancellationToken.cpp -o /Users/mattao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ComputerVIsion-bnbfvcebogxuupamklqlxmffldfb/Build/Intermediates/ComputerVision.build/Debug/ComputerVision.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CancellationToken.o

In file included from /Users/mattao/Code/Common-ComputerVision/Shared/Common/CancellationToken.cpp:1:
In file included from ../Shared/Common/CancellationToken.h:3:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:4312:9: error: no matching member function for call to '__enable_weak_this'
    __r.__enable_weak_this(__r.__ptr_);
    ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:4672:29: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::shared_ptr<volatile bool>::make_shared<bool &>' requested here
    return shared_ptr<_Tp>::make_shared(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
                            ^
/Users/mattao/Code/Common-ComputerVision/Shared/Common/CancellationToken.cpp:9:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::make_shared<volatile bool, bool &>' requested here
   _isCancelled = make_shared<volatile bool>( cancelled );
                  ^
In file included from /Users/mattao/Code/Common-ComputerVision/Shared/Common/CancellationToken.cpp:1:
In file included from ../Shared/Common/CancellationToken.h:3:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:4036:10: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'element_type *' (aka 'volatile bool *') to 'const void *' for 1st argument; take the address of the argument with &
    void __enable_weak_this(const void*) _NOEXCEPT {}
         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:4029:9: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'enable_shared_from_this<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'volatile bool'
        __enable_weak_this(const enable_shared_from_this<_Yp>* __e) _NOEXCEPT
        ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Is this in a C++ file or Objective-C file? The compiler would be more specific and should give reference to line number. You would need to look at the output and with Xcode, you'd need to expand the error to get more detailed info.

Comment: Great call.  I found how to expand the error.  Edited the question

Comment: It looks like a `.cpp` file is including `<memory>`

Comment: Btw you can expand it more. If you look to the far right you should see the icon with the series of horiz lines. This will give even more info

Comment: If that doesn't give anything meaningful you'll prolly need to post some code. I assume memory is included before the other .h in the .cpp?

Comment: Found it, adding to post now

Comment: It would be helpful for you to post some code.

Comment: Sorry at first I wasn't sure if it was relevant.  I put the method that the error is pointing at

Comment: How have you defined `_isCancelled`? As `std::shared_ptr<volatile bool> _isCancelled;`? I'm using Xcode 8 right now. But this works for me. I was using C++14, but switched the compiler back to C++11 (-std=gnu++11). My other settings are same as yours. Also note my test case wasn't exact as I just used `(false)` for the argument during construction

Comment: As an aside, seeing what you are doing, it is not clear to me why you need shared ptr here versus just a normal data member. Given you are using a lambda and capturing this, it certainly doesn't need a shared ptr to do any of it. Keep in mind I do not have any other parts of code.

Comment: Yeah so I talked to the internal team that wrote the code, and they changed the `volatile bool` to `atomic` (`_isCancelled = make_shared<std::atomic<bool>>( cancelled );`) and all is well :)

I am the only person on the team that's still on 10.10.5, so I couldn't upgrade my OS to get download the Command Line Tools with the LLVM update that would let me compile